# Why is UIBezierPath's addArcWithCenter adding two curves?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a vertically rounded bezier path with a frame of size 708x80 using this:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[maskPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(cornerRadius, cornerRadius) radius:cornerRadius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270) clockwise:YES];
[maskPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(size.width - cornerRadius, cornerRadius) radius:cornerRadius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) clockwise:YES];
[maskPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(size.width - cornerRadius, size.height - cornerRadius) radius:cornerRadius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) clockwise:YES];
[maskPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(cornerRadius, size.height - cornerRadius) radius:cornerRadius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180) clockwise:YES];

[maskPath closePath];
```

and it creates this path:

```
<MoveTo {1.4921397e-13, 39.999996}>,
<CurveTo {40, 7.1054274e-15} {1.9312909e-06, 17.908607} {17.908611, -2.6343716e-07}>,
<LineTo {668, 7.1054274e-15}>,
<CurveTo {708, 40} {690.09137, 2.6343719e-07} {708, 17.908609}>,
<LineTo {708, 40}>,
<CurveTo {668, 80} {708, 62.091389} {690.09137, 80}>,
<CurveTo {668, 80} {668, 80} {668, 80}>,
<LineTo {40, 80}>,
<CurveTo {4.2632564e-14, 40} {17.908609, 80} {-9.6564531e-07, 62.091389}>,
<CurveTo {1.4921397e-13, 39.999996} {6.631732e-14, 40} {1.0184446e-13, 39.999996}>,
<Close>
```

Why does it create two curves only for the bottom right and left corners? Moreso, why is the first doubled curve starting from the exact same point?

Comment: <LineTo {708, 40}> and <CurveTo {668, 80} {668, 80} {668, 80}> are zero-length objects, really - points

Comment: @MBo, But why does it add them? I changed the second arc's end angle to `1` and it didn't add the first duplicated curve. Also, how comes it looks good if it's creating a curve from {668, 80} to another point and then it creates a point-like curve in the same {668, 80} point, basically going backwards.

Comment: Perhaps artifacts due to numerical errors (I don't know internals of addArcWithCenter).